# GNURadio companion 3.10.4.0 error with "Protocol Formatter"

Tags: gnuradio-companion

[image][image]while using "Protocol Formatter" in my OFDM design, I got the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
  1. gnuradio.digital.digital_python.protocol_formatter_bb(format: gnuradio.digital.digital_python.header_format_base, len_tag_key: str = 'packet_len')
Invoked with: <gnuradio.digital.digital_python.packet_header_ofdm object at 0x000001CA1B820EF0>, 'packet_len'
```

and the parameters I passed to this block are as below:

`Format Obj. : header_formatter.base()`

`Length Tag name: "Packet_len"`

[image]

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated !!

Comment: You should give more information about your gnu radio graph, otherwise it's hard to give an answer

Comment: my apology, i have attached the radio graph along with protocol formatter ,

Comment: You should also post the full error message: it should look something like  `typeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. gnuradio.digital.digital_python.protocol_formatter_bb(format: gnuradio.digital.digital_python.header_format_base, len_tag_key: str = 'packet_len')

Invoked with: <gnuradio.digital.digital_python.constellation_bpsk object at 0x000001CD925F0FF0>, 'packet_len'`

Comment: in main tb = top_block_cls(freq=options.freq)

  File "D:\GNURadio\Demo13_OFDM_TX1.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.digital_protocol_formatter_bb_0 = digital.protocol_formatter_bb(header_formatter.base(), "packet_len")
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
   

 1. gnuradio.digital.digital_python.protocol_formatter_bb(format: gnuradio.digital.digital_python.header_format_base, len_tag_key: str = 'packet_len')

Invoked with: <gnuradio.digital.digital_python.packet_header_ofdm object at 0x000001CA1B820EF0>, 'packet_len'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your graph, and I got the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:

gnuradio.digital.digital_python.protocol_formatter_bb(format: gnuradio.digital.digital_python.header_format_base, len_tag_key: str = 'packet_len')
```

So the two parameters for the block are of the type: `header_format_base` and `string`.

But the message that you get is `invoked with: <gnuradio.digital.digital_python.packet_header_ofdm object` which is not the right type.

If you use the following for the Format Obj (type it in or create a variable with it): `digital.header_format_ofdm(occupied_carriers, 1, length_tag_key,)` it should work (occupied_carriers and length_tag_key are variable in your graph) as it returns a header_format_base object

I found this example on [github](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/a94c4f228750213c20ea51a3e9a31283942052f1/gr-digital/examples/ofdm/tx_ofdm.grc), as linked from the [gnuradio wiki](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Protocol_Formatter), but you have to dig a bit in the github history, as the protocol formatter block was removed from the lasted version

Comment: Thanking you, by following the Format Obj : digital.header_format_ofdm(occupied_carriers, 1, length_tag_key,)"  i am able to get spectrum  .  Thanking you once again

Comment: @user3743908 , glad it helps. You can mark the answer as accepted, so that your question is shown as solved